# Модификация алгоритма поиска подстроки методом Рабина-Карпа для потоковой обработки данных

Tags: c, алгоритм, структуры-данных

Есть функция, которая выполняет поиск подстроки в строке методом Рабина-Карпа и выводит позиции всех символов в тексте, совпавших с шаблоном (позиции в тексте нумеруются от 1):

```
int rabin_kapr_matcer(char *Text, char *Pattern, int d, int q) {
    int n = strlen(Text);
    int m = strlen(Pattern);
    int h = (int)pow(d, m - 1) % q;
    int p = 0;
    int t = 0;

    int found = 0;
    int founded_count = 0;

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int s = 0;
    
    //предварительная обработка
    for (i = 1; i < m; i++) {
        p = (d * p + Pattern[i]) % q;
        t = (d * t + Text[i]) % q;
    }

    //Проверка
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        if (p == t) {
            found = 1;
            for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                if (Pattern[j] != Text[i + j]) {
                    found = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (found) {
                //вывод совпадающих символов
                for (s = 0; s < m; ++s) {
                    printf("%d ", i + 1 + s);
                }

                ++founded_count;
            }
        }
        else {
            t = (d*(t - ((Text[i]*h) % q)) + Text[i + m]) % q;
        }

    }

    return founded_count;
}
```

Пример.

Вход:

> example
>
> this is simple example

Выход:

> 16 17 18 19 20 21 22

Надо модифицировать алгоритм для поиска в больших файлах, когда нет возможности загрузить весь текст в память.
Какую структуру данных стоит использовать и насколько при этом изменится алгоритм?

Comment: Думаю стоит сказать, что функцию писал по Кормену, все переменные названы в соответствии с книгой.
Сам думал, что для потоковой обработки можно использовать кольцевой буфер, но кажется это не лучшее решение в данном случае, т.к. в кэш-функции используется значение длинны текста.

Comment: а в чём именно вопрос то? я бы использовал цикличную перезапись массива. Буффер размера такого же как и длина шаблона.

Comment: Вопрос возник из-за:
1) n = len(Text); - если длина будет изменяться во время работы программы, не будет ли ошибок в расчете хэша?
2) Вопрос с разрывами между фрагментами как вы уже сказали можно решить буфером, размера такого же, как и длина шаблона

Comment: PS: Или имеется ввиду считывать файл небольшими блоками, при этом на каждой перезаписи сдвигать в начало последние m символов? Ну и запускать функцию отдельно для каждого блока